# Joomla overwrites headers

Tags: php, joomla, http-headers

I'm serving downloads to mobile phones (running Android, that is) and Android seems to be accepting only [specific headers](http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/).
Now this is what I'm trying to do in Joomla.

```
    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setMimeEncoding('application/octet-stream');
```

This works but for some reason Joomla is adding charset=utf-8 to my headers, thus the downloads don't work. How do I get rid of this charset (which turns out to be pretty useless with binary files anyway)?

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Joomla 1.7, but I guess that doesn't really make a difference to 11

Comment: It makes a difference because Joomla! 1.5 has different mechanisms for returning raw data than the 1.7/2.5 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Joomla 2.5 (untested for lower or higher versions)
Joomla appends its own headers, this is why you need to use JResponse::clearHeaders();

```
$filename = basename($file);
ob_end_clean();
JResponse::clearHeaders();
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream', true);
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename.';', true);
JResponse::sendHeaders();
echo JFile::read($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.3 introduces [`header_remove`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php), which could probably be used in your case (though I have little experience with Joomla).

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, the system runs on 5.2.13 and I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

For the records:
It can't be done within Joomla's MVC structure as there's always a charset (and other headers) attached, so I ended up importing and initializing Joomla's framework from a separate php file, like so:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

// real path depending on the type of server
// change the number of returns/level needed in your path relative to the position of your script in your directory
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../..' ));
define( 'JPATH_COMPONENT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

// loading framework of Joomla!
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

/* 
... some other joomla stuff ...
*/
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.zip"'));
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
readfile($lfile);
```

So, basically, load the framework, use the database or whatever and call the header function on your own. Hope, this helps someone else.